# How to represent a non-empty array?

Tags: phpstan

I tried using intersection of types

```
/**
 * @param array&nonEmpty $users
 */
function sayHello($users): void {
    echo 'Hello, ' . $users[0];
}
```

but it complains:

```
PHPDoc tag @param for parameter $users contains unresolvable type.
```

([live demo](https://phpstan.org/r/b6c85812-ca28-4fa0-8eb3-57d284a8e6c6))

If I strip the annotation to just `nonEmpty`, the error changes to

```
Parameter $users of function sayHello() has invalid typehint type nonEmpty
```

I do see the class responsible for the `nonEmpty` type in the [source tree](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-src/blob/0.12.9/src/Type/Accessory/NonEmptyArrayType.php) as well as mentioned several times in the [tests](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-src/blob/87a71c32b8c3dea1b25fdff3c4f2a1055c6133e3/tests/PHPStan/Type/TypeCombinatorTest.php#L2143) and [issues](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/2448#issuecomment-534880692) but I just could not make it work.

Comment: Hi, it's better to ask in GitHub PHPStan issues rather than here. Some types are only internally represented in PHPStan but you can't express them in PHPDocs.

Comment: Opened https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/3045

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to provide an answer for those coming from search engines:

PHPStan now has `non-empty-array` type you can use. [Here](https://phpstan.org/r/c5599b61-77b5-4390-85e0-da5c85ee1684) is an example.